# Variation of $\log(-\det g_{\mu\nu})$ for Einstein -Hilbert action

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, variational-calculus, trace

In Einstein-Hilbert variation is needed the variation of the determinant of a metric tensor. For convenience, firstly evaluated the variation of $\log(-\det g_{\mu\nu})$ considering $\det g_{\mu\nu}<0$
 $$\delta\log( -\det g_{\mu\nu})=\log[-\det(g_{\mu\nu}+\delta g_{\mu\nu})]-\log[-\det g_{\mu\nu}]=$$

$$
\log\det g^{\mu\nu}(g_{\mu\nu}+\delta g_{\mu\nu})=\log\det(\hat {1}+g^{\mu\nu}\delta g_{\mu\nu})=
$$

$$
Tr\log(\hat {1}+g^{\mu\nu}\delta g_{\mu\nu})=Tr(g^{\mu\nu}\delta g_{\mu\nu})
$$
How to proceed then? Is $Tr(g^{\mu\nu}\delta g_{\mu\nu})=g^{\mu\nu}\delta g_{\mu\nu}?$ Following that $Tr$ (Scalar)=Scalar the identity must be true. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To account for the minus sign, one can e.g. use the following trick
$$ -\det g~\stackrel{(2)}{=}~+\det M, \tag{1}$$
where the matrix $$M^{\mu}{}_{\nu}~:=~(\eta^{-1})^{\mu\lambda} g_{\lambda\nu}\tag{2} $$
has positive determinant, and $\eta_{\mu\nu}$ is a fixed fiducial reference metric of determinant $-1$, e.g. the  Minkowski metric. Then the infinitesimal variation is
$$\begin{align} \delta\ln(-\det g)~\stackrel{(1)}{=}~& \delta\ln\det M\cr ~=~&\delta {\rm tr}\ln M \cr 
~=~&{\rm tr}( M^{-1}\delta M)\cr 
~\stackrel{(2)}{=}~&{\rm tr}( g^{-1}\eta\eta^{-1} \delta g)\cr
~=~&{\rm tr}(g^{-1} \delta g)\cr
~=~&(g^{-1} \delta g)^{\mu}{}_{\mu}\cr
~=~&( g^{-1})^{\mu\nu} \delta g_{\nu\mu}. \end{align}\tag{3}$$

Comment: Here is used component-free notation.And, in component-notation is it $\rm tr (g^{-1} \delta g)=\rm tr (g^{\mu\nu}\delta g_{\mu\nu})=g^{\mu\nu}\delta g_{\mu\nu}$ due to $g^{\mu\nu}\delta g_{\mu\nu}$ being scalar?

Comment: In your above comment, note that the two traces are different: one is over a $4\times 4$ matrix and one is over a $1\times 1$ matrix.

Comment: $\rm tr (g^{-1}\delta g)=g^{\mu\nu}\delta g_{\mu\nu}$ how is this derived?

Comment: I updated the answer.

Comment: The important thing causing the confusion here was not knowing the $\rm tr (A B)=A^{\mu\nu}B_{\mu\nu}$. The trace of matrix multiplication.

Answer (score 1):

Use the chain rule to evaluate the variation of the logarithm: let $F[X]$ be a functional of $X = X(\tau)$. Then
$$\delta \log(F[X]) = \frac{1}{F[X]} \delta F[X]$$
In your example (suppressing indices on the metric):
$$ \delta \log(-\det(g)) = \frac{1}{\det(g)} \delta \det(g) $$
You should then use Jacobi's formula:
$$ \delta \det(g) = \det(g)g^{\mu\nu}\delta g_{\mu\nu}$$

edit: I have misunderstood the point of the question: it seems like OP was looking to derive this final result, and their claim in the final line is true and verifies Jacobi's result.

Comment: Jacobi's formula is also derived using this approach.

Answer (score 1):

Using indices can be confusing. You are actually calling $g_{\mu \nu}$ the metric tensor as a matrix, not a particular element of this matrix.

Your derivation is correct until the second last step. It becomes clearer if you use the substitution/notation

\begin{align}
g_{\mu \nu} &\to g \\
g^{\mu \nu} &\to g^{-1} \\
\delta g_{\mu \nu} &\to \delta g
\end{align}

At this point your last equation becomes

$$
\mathrm{Tr}{ (g^{-1} \delta g )} = g^{lm} {\delta g_{lm}} \,
$$

where I used summation notation for repeated indexes. Now taking the derivative with respect to the variation of $g$ should be obvious.

Comment: $Tr(g^{\mu\nu}\delta g_{\mu\nu})=g^{\mu\nu}\delta g_{\mu\nu}?$

Comment: What you write is confusing but is correct. What you write is in fact Tr(Tr(...)). Clearly $Tr(a)= a$ if $a$ is a complex number. Often though we write $a$ for the identity matrix in the relative space in which case you would get an additional factor given by the dimension of the space.

Comment: But if you do things properly you never get to compute the trace twice (although of course the result doesn't change).

Comment: Basically you are using a wrong notation. In all the equations you don't use summation convention and the product is just matrix product. The argument of the log in your equation must be a matrix as well as the argument of the trace. But in the very last equation you seem to switch notation and assume summation over repeated indexes because the result must be a scalar.

Comment: How do you correct the notation I am using. Could you show it? Comment it with edition, please.

Comment: I added some explanation, is it clearer now?